# OpenERP 7: Hide Whole Form Header or It's Elements

Tags: odoo

I am trying do display a form in read only mode;

I am trying to hide/disable the whole form header if posible; if not individual elements: bread crumbs, buttons (edit, create, more, delete, duplicate, next, previous) from the Form.

as shown in red selections
[image]

I tried modifying the invisible attribute using xpath as shown in 
[hide buttons Create, Delete and Edit](http://forum.openerp.com/forum/topic30054.html)

```
    <xpath expr='/form/group/button[@string="Edit"]' position="replace">
         <button type="action" attrs="{'invisible': [('uid','!=',0)]}" />
    </xpath>
```

but all I can manage is this:
[image]

1. How to hide the header section or it's individual elements?
2. What Is the best practice in OpenErp 7 to make a form in read only mode.

Thanks

Comment: for now I resort to using CSS to hide the header; add style element in the form:                                                     <style>                                                     .openerp .oe_view_manager table.oe_view_manager_header { display:none }                                                 </style>

Comment: Your comment works like charm dear...

Answer (score 0):

Hide it in /openerp/addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml at line number 510

Answer (score 0):

To hide the more button go to /addons/web/static/src/css/base.css and find:

```
.openerp .oe_sidebar {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and replace it with:

```
.openerp .oe_sidebar {
    display: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will hide the element so that the browser does not render it, it however will still be visible in the source code.